# Variables as hash values in Python

Tags: python

How can I link a variable to a dictionary value in Python?
Consider the following code:

```
a_var = 10
a_dict = {'varfield':a_var, 'first':25, 'second':57} 

# a_dict['varfield'] == 10 now

a_var = 700   
# a_dict['varfield'] == 10 anyway
```

So is there a way to link the value of a variable to a field in a dictictionary without looking up for that field an updating it's value manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set the value of the dictionary key, to an object that you can change the value of.

For example like this:

```
class valueContainer(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value.__repr__()


v1 = valueContainer(1)

myDict = {'myvar': v1}
print myDict 
#{'myvar': 1}

v1.value = 2 
print myDict
#{'myvar': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
w = [410]

myDict = {'myvar': w}

print myDict 
#{'myvar': [410]}

w[0] = 520

print myDict
#{'myvar': [520]}
```

That's the version of the code of M4rtini with a list instead of an instance of a class.
He is obliged to modify `v1` (in fact its attribute `value`) with the instruction `v1.value = ...`,
I am obliged to modify the value in the list with `w[0] = ...`

The reason to act like this is that what you erroneously called a variable, and that is in fact an **identifier**, doesn't designates a variable in the sense of a "chunk of memory whose content can change" but *references* an **object** to which the identifier is *binded*, object whose value cannot change because it is an  immutable object.

Please read the explanations of the documentation on the data model and the execution model of Python which is quite different from the ones of languages such as Java, PHP, etc.

Comment: @yari Thank you. - Note that I've corrected my answer: the results are not ``{'myvar': 410}`` and ``{'myvar': 520}`` but ``{'myvar': [410]}`` and ``{'myvar': [520]}``